# Magento 2.3.2 Rest API Showing 401 Authorization Required

Tags: magento2.3, error, rest-api

I am trying to use the Magento 2.3 Rest API, using token authorization. when I try to GET data back from one of the endpoints using the token in an Authorization Bearer heading, I get an HTTP 401 Basic Authentication error. The problem is that the server requires Basic Authentication.My magento site host from AWS.
site url is to https://........
In my local project API is working but live site not work API.

**Postman error**

> ```
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <title>401 Authorization Required</title>
>     </head>
>     <body bgcolor="white">
>         <center>
>             <h1>401 Authorization Required</h1>
>         </center>
>         <hr>
>         <center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

Please give me solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved this issue when I have disabled Nginx letsencrypt authentication then the issue was resolved.

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
     server  unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}

server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name consumablesandstores.com www.consumablesandstores.com;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/consumable-store;
     include /var/www/html/consumable-store/nginx.conf.sample;

     //Server Auth
     #auth_basic "Restricted Content";
     #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

}
```